# Easy get/set of denormalized list of strings - messy solution to triggering `set`

Tags: c#, .net, denormalization

I'm denormalizing a one-to-many into a `List<int>`:

```
    public string DbUsersMessaged { get; set; }
    public List<int> UsersMessaged {
        get {
            return string.IsNullOrEmpty(DbUsersMessaged) ? new List<int>() : DbUsersMessaged.Split(',').Select(Int32.Parse).ToList();
        }
        set {
            DbUsersMessaged = value != null ? String.Join(",", value) : null;
        }
    }
```

To read, I can query `UsersMessaged.Contains(id)`.

To write, I'd like to simply do `UsersMessaged.Add(id)`, but this doesn't work because `set` isn't called.

For now, I'm doing this to trigger the `set`:

```
  UsersMessaged = UsersMessaged.AddReassign(user);
  public static List<int> AddReassign(this List<int> list, int item)
    {
        var tempList = list;
        if (list.Contains(item))
            return list;
        tempList.Add(item);
        list = tempList;
        return list;
    }
```

But this is awful because next week I'll forget that I can't just do `Add` and waste a bunch of time remembering this crap.  What's a cleaner way to go about setting a denormalized `List<T>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A cleaner way to do this is to implement your own List and override the Add method

```
public class DbList : List<int>
{
    public override void Add(int value)
    {
        //perform your logic here.
    }
}
```

And you can have your string value in the DbList instance.

Comment: `Add(T value)` is not virtual.

Comment: I'm having a little trouble converting the above.  How would I handle the `get` case here?

Comment: @SB2055 you should add a string property to have the get